Membership end date & status does not update after contribution payment (renewal)
After schedule reminder mail sent about annual memberships renewal with tokenized link, members create an online contribution for their membership extension.
For unknown reason end date & status does not update by civicrm.
So after end date of membership the status is getting into Grace mode ignoring any association to the latest contribution and we need to update the membership extend manually.
Meanwhile cron jobs execute without errors.
Also looking at Civimember membership type and rules i cannot find any misconfiguration that may reason to this.
CiviCRM 5.43.0, WP 5.9.9
Do you have any ideas why this may happen ?

Have you checked your Scheduled Job for Membership Status is running without errors? Though that would not explain the End Date issue. Where does your link send them - does it go to a Contribution page that has the relevant Membership Types enabled on it?

@petednz-fuzion Yes, scheduled job is running without errors. Renewal Link send user to Contribution page with Membership Types enabled and auto-renew option disabled. Contribution data entry form is through Caldera Form and Stripe payment webhook is sending back to CiviCRM without error.

I am not very WP savvy. so this isn't a civi form? is it a CF? if so best you tag this as such. may get more knowledge folk looking.

or ask in https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/channels/wordpress

or add more info to your Q so other can follow the logic in the dark
